# Anychart - How do I display hatching in icons of the legend?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex-5, anychart

If I use hatching in the chart (built-in Anychart in Oracle Application Express 5), the legend icons remain filled in solid color, hatching is not displayed on them. Also I do not see such settings in the xml sections of the legend and others. Any ideas?

Comment: The only idea - JavaScript code on page load which changes `fill` attribute of an SVG element.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can set the series hatch settings with XML, e.g. with

```
<series enabled="true" series_type="bar" x_scale="0" y_scale="1">'+
'                <hatch_fill type="horizontal" color="#424242" thickness="1" size="5"/>' + ... +

</series>'
```

like is shown in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/pwb15quu/

2) if it won't help, please contact us via support@anychart.com with the full code.